# Unable to classify

Tags: matlab, knn

I'm new at matlab and I would like to make cross validation 10 folds, then classify the matrix and then show its ROC.

```
indices = crossvalind ('KFold', labels, 10); 

cp= classperf (labels);

for i= 1:10 
   test= find (indices == i);
   train= find (indices ~= i);
   class =fitcknn (ANorm, labels);
   classperf (cp, class, test);
end

cp.errorRate;

plotroc(class,labels);
```

However, I keep getting theses errors:

```
Error using classreg.learning.internal.DisallowVectorOps/subsref (line 16)
You cannot index into an object of class ClassificationKNN using () indexing.

Error in classperf (line 219)
gps = varargin{1}(:);

Error in M (line 108)
classperf (cp, class, test);
```

Can someone please tell me why these errors are happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use the `predict` method. I don't have `fitcknn`, thus I have used `ClassificationKNN.fit`. The `class` object you get in your code, cannot be used with `classperf`. You are supposed to send numeric/string labels to it. Thus the error.

```
labels=[zeros(100,1);ones(100,1)];
ANorm=[1+2*randn(100,30);4+1.5*randn(100,30)];

indices = crossvalind ('KFold', labels, 10); 
cp=classperf(labels);

for i= 1:10 
   test=  (indices == i);
   train=  (indices ~= i);
   labelsTest=labels(test);
   mdl =ClassificationKNN.fit (ANorm, labels);
   labelsPredict = predict(mdl,ANorm(test,:));
   classperf(cp,labelsPredict,test);
end

cp.errorRate
```